# Callback for Android refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync in Facebook Android SDK 4.1+

Tags: android, ios, facebook

In Android, I'm calling `refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync()` but there doesn't appear to be a callback.  I've registered callbackManager before invoking `refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync()` and it never gets called, and neither does `onActivityResult`.

Doc doesn't say anything either:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/

In iOS, there is a completion handler.

```
+ (void)refreshCurrentAccessToken:(FBSDKGraphRequestHandler)completionHandler;
```

What is the best practice to use in the event a user revoked their token or removed permissions?

I assume on IOS I would check in the `GraphRequest` completion handler, but don't see what's the recommended way on Android with no callback.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked my answer? It is the correct way if you are, like me, mostly using FB to login to your server (by using FB id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot refresh the token if the user has revoked the token. You can only refresh it if the current access token is still valid.

The method also calls Graph API directly, which is why there's no onActivityResult being called.

If there is a successful refresh, then the access token will be updated and you can use the AccessTokenTracker to get notifications.

Lastly, why are you calling this method directly? Normally just by using the Graph API the SDK will refresh the token automatically for you.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly this is because of the poor documentation of the SDK by FaceBook.

You have to set a tracker for `AccessToken`, similar to what you'd do with `Profile`.

My code for that is as below:

```
private AccessTokenTracker mAccessTokenTracker;

private void loginToMyFbApp() {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        mAccessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                mAccessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
                if(currentAccessToken == null) {
                    //(the user has revoked your permissions -
                    //by going to his settings and deleted your app)
                    //do the simple login to FaceBook
                }
                else {
                    //you've got the new access token now.
                    //AccessToken.getToken() could be same for both
                    //parameters but you should only use "currentAccessToken"
                }
            }
        };
        AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync();
    }
    else {
        //do the simple login to FaceBook
    }
}
```

### Edit

Removed `startTracking()` call as rightly pointed out by **Astrount** in [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961606/callback-for-android-refreshcurrentaccesstokenasync-in-facebook-android-sdk-4-1/33151438?noredirect=1#comment59776592_33151438).

Comment: Nice implementation, but you don't need mAccessTokenTracker.startTracking(); as new AccessTokenTracker() internally calls startTracking();

Comment: @Astrount thanks. You're right; I've removed that line now. :)