# Facebook Profile.getCurrentProfile() is always returns null after the first login

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

For the first time when I login into the app through Facebook, I'm getting profile from `Profile.getCurrentProfile();`

Where as when I exit the app and launch again, It was already logged in. So I can call directly `Profile.getCurrentProfile();` is returning null.

**Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page);
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    // For the first launch the profile will be null
    displayProfileName(profile);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {

                        @Override
                        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(
                                Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                            profileTracker.stopTracking();
                            Profile.setCurrentProfile(currentProfile);
                            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                            displayProfileName(profile);
                        }
                    };
                    profileTracker.startTracking();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (profileTracker != null) {
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
    AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}
/**
*
* Method to display the Profile Name 
*/
private void displayProfileName(Profile profile) {
    if (profile != null) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, profile.getName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
    super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}
```

Comment: Your `AccesToken` might have expired.

Comment: No. I can use the access token for another requests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [facebook login api 4.0: Profile.getCurrentProfile null when logged in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642759/facebook-login-api-4-0-profile-getcurrentprofile-null-when-logged-in)

Comment: But after the second launch of the app. onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) will not call right?

Comment: For the first time onSuccess will be called and i we can get the Profile, but for the second launch, how can we

Comment: can you post your complete code?

Comment: Please check the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92944/discussion-between-vipul-asri-and-user3607798).

Comment: @vipul_asri were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: @Sufian code i tried was working for me. `if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null) {Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken(); if(Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null) { //if it available
Log.i(TAG, Profile.getCurrentProfile().getName() + ", " + Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId() + ", " + Profile.getCurrentProfile().getLinkUri());
}
}`

Comment: @vipul_asri this code written in any of the answers below so how about you post this as an answer and mark it? Would be helpful for others as well. :)

Comment: @Sufian this code was suggested by me to questioner but he said this isn't working for him and i am not the one who asked the question so i can't accept my answer if i post it.

Comment: @vipul_asri sorry for mistaking you as the asker. I will ask him :)

Comment: @user3607798 it seems that you have found an answer. Please post the code and mark it as answer. It would help the community and yourself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases in this:

1. For first login, follow [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29652674/1276636).
2. For second login, you will need to refresh your `AccessToken` and then fetch the profile. Refreshing token code can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33151438/1276636) but the code below has it (for simplification).

The code is taken from [FB's dreadful documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph#userdata)).

You can put this code straight into your app, where the comment says "case 1", just invoke your normal FB login.

```
private AccessTokenTracker mAccessTokenTracker;

private void loginToMyFbApp() {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        mAccessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                mAccessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
                if(currentAccessToken == null) {
                    //(the user has revoked your permissions -
                    //by going to his settings and deleted your app)
                    //do the simple login to FaceBook
                    //case 1
                }
                else {
                    //you've got the new access token now.
                    //AccessToken.getToken() could be same for both
                    //parameters but you should only use "currentAccessToken"
                    //case 2
                    fetchProfile();
                }
            }
        };
        mAccessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync();
    }
    else {
        //do the simple login to FaceBook
        //case 1
    }
}

private void fetchProfile() {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    // this is where you should have the profile
                    Log.v("fetched info", object.toString());
                }
            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link"); //write the fields you need
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of accessing Profile.getCurrentProfile()

use access token and make graph request in onSuccess()

( It worked for me)

here snippet of code :

```
FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        Log.v("profile track", (DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT).format(loginResult.getAccessToken().getExpires())));
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        try {

                            String name = object.getString("name");
                            String email = object.getString("email");
                            String id = object.getString("id");
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, name + " " + " " + email + " " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    /*write  your code  that is to be executed after successful login*/


                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
    }
};
```

Answer (score -4):

Call `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` once you get the profile details.

Comment: I dont want to logout from the facebook.

Comment: @user3607798 what exactly you want to do? Can u explain me the flow?

Comment: It's not logical to logout after logging in.