# Android facebook sdk AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() returns null

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

On application startup I show facebook login window using the following code.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity,    Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
```

I got response `onSuccess` which is ok. AccessToken exists and `Profile.getCurrentProfile()` also returns valid profile. BUt after I shut down the application and open again `AccessToken.getCurrentToken()` returns `null`. Does anyone have the same problem? I can't understand what's going on.

I am using latest Facebook SDK. 4.x

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29374616/1384010

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook AccessToken.getAccessToken is null on opening of app even after first login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366945/facebook-accesstoken-getaccesstoken-is-null-on-opening-of-app-even-after-first-l)

Comment: I have seen the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/29374616/1384010 and this is not problem. AccessToken.getCurrentToken() is null but on accessTokenTracker change the valid token comes.
I have created another blank app and everything works there fine. But this is existing app and I changed facebook sdk from 3.x. And decided to rewrite facebook related code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found the problem. `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize` method was not in `Application.onCreate` method. I thought I had But it was at different place. 
So ALWAYS call `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize` method from `onCreate` method at the top after calling `super.onCreate`

Answer (score 3):

I would say make sure the user hasn't revoked access to the app from their facebook settings. Accesstoken null basically means your app isn't authorized or you are calling logOut() somewhere else. You should go back to the login screen if this happens.