# Checking whether or not Facebook Android SDK has been initialized

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So Facebook's android SDK has been known to take some time (100ms-500ms) to spin up and load all of its necessary resources.

[Facebook AccessToken.getAccessToken is null on opening of app even after first login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366945/facebook-accesstoken-getaccesstoken-is-null-on-opening-of-app-even-after-first-l)

So what I have been doing is just using a callback that waits until the sdk has finished loading before executing the necessary operations

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext(), new FacebookSdk.InitializeCallback() 
{
    @Override
    public void onInitialized() 
    {
        // running this here, since AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken 
        // might not be initialized otherwise

        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null)
        {
           // redirect to login activity
        } 
        else 
        {
            // redirect to profile activity
        }
    }
});
```

But now in the newer versions of the sdk, `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize` has been deprecated. And now I dont know how to insure that the sdk is initialized before calling `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken`

Only thing I can think of right now is just having the thread wait for 100ms-500ms, but this seams like the jankiest of patches.